# How to configure MySQL data source for PhpStorm?

Tags: mysql, configuration, phpstorm

I have a legacy PHP project using MySQL. PhpStorm discovers that there are MySQL queries inside the project, and asks me to provide a data source for them.

This opens this window:

[image: Data Sources and Drivers for MySQL]

Yet I am totally confused on how to provide the credentials to my MySQL database. I expected a mask to enter my MySQL host, username, password and target database name. Yet I cannot find this in here.

How to configure a MySQL data source in PhpStorm?

Comment: Start with clicking `+` button on toolbar to add actual Data Source. Right now you are looking at default driver definitions only... https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Databases+and+SQL+Editor+in+PhpStorm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new source for your projet, click on the green "+" icon and select mysql in the list of drivers. It should display fields for database info including username and password.

[image: Project Data source in PHPStorm]

Comment: but if you have different port than default 3306 so you need to upd/upd tdefault template to proper detect connection with mysql or others  then update port (in answer screen) !

Answer (score 3):

You have to click on the green `+`, top left corner.
Then Click on MySQL, and you will be able to enter DB informations.